# Why can't I delete a row from the database?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php, I have a customer table that I can retrieve all data. I added delete button to delete rows but its deleting only on html page and not deleting from database(when I refresh all data returns). can anyone help? I don't know what to do with the code

php:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hamatkin');

  if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
     $id=$_GET['customer_id'];
     $del="DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id='".$id."'";
     mysqli_query($connect,$del);
    echo  "$_GET['customer_id']";
  }
?>
```

controller:

```
 $scope.delete = function(deletingId, index){
          var params = $.param({"customer_id":deletingId})
          $http({
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            url: "api/deleteCustomer.php?customer_id=?" + deletingId ,
            method:"GET",
            data:params

          }).success(function(data){

            $scope.customers.splice(index,1);
            console.log(data);
          });
```

Comment: Not `customer_id=?` but `customer_id=`

Comment: @nospor still the same....

Comment: Check response of your request in some console eg. Firebug for Firefox

Comment: First are you getting id in your PHP code?? and also echo that query and try to execute it on PhpMyadmin or other tools.

Comment: how do I do that in phpmyadmin ? how do I echo a query?

Comment: use `echo $del` after query string. Then give `exit`. You can see the query in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

change your $del with following

```
$del="DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id=".$id;
```

Comment: echo $del and try to run that directly on database, if there is any problem in your query then it will tell you.

Comment: how do I run it directly on database?

Comment: which stack you are using? if you are using wamp or xampp then go to phpMyAdmin and run that $del echo output on phpMyAdmin console.

Comment: im running on wamp

Comment: if you are familiar with phpMyAdmin then do that otherwise if you are using windows machine then open cmd any type mysql - u <username> -p <yourpassword> then select your database by running command use <databasename> and run $del query.

Comment: im running with phpmyadmin what to write their?

Comment: in phpMyAdmin  open console then select database then run output of the "echo $del"  on console.

Comment: it won't delete from the database

Comment: what are your getting in response?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Post your query here.

Comment: @SameerK echo $del

Comment: I am asking what are you getting after running your query in phpMyAdmin console.

Comment: @dgoku I answerd...this is what im getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: do one thing replace your code with this 

```?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hamatkin');

  if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
     $id=$_GET['customer_id'];
     $del="DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id='".$id."'";
     mysqli_query($connect,$del);
    echo  $del;
  }
?>```

Comment: i think you are running on browser console. just run it on  phpMyAdmin console.

Comment: @kapi -  you need to post the output of the `echo $del`

Comment: in navigation bar of the phpMyAdmin there must be a "sql" click on that it will open a console the write there 'use <yourdatabasename>' and then run the output of the 'echo $del'

Comment: leave every thing else just tell me the customer_id ?

Comment: @dgoku I wrote : use <hamatkin> echo $del ;
 the output: Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected character. (near "$" at position 20)
SQL query:

use <hamatkin> echo $del

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<hamatkin> echo $del' at line 1

Comment: @dgoku what do u mean to tell you customer_id?

Comment: okey then run "use hamatkin"  and then run "DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id=1"

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data:params`, you are already sending id in url

```
$scope.delete = function(deletingId, index){
$http({
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  url: "api/deleteCustomer.php?customer_id=" + deletingId ,
  method:"GET"
}).success(function(data){
  $scope.customers.splice(index,1);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: its still the same....this is how I activate in html page <td><button ng-click="delete(customers.customer_id, $index)">Delete</button><td>

Comment: Also remove `?` after customer_id, and also check in db ?

Comment: how do I check on my database? what to write on the query?

Comment: have you not credential to see db ? also what you get after running ajax in your browserss console ?

Comment: I can see the database but I'm new at this don't know how to write a query to check my code

Comment: just open phpmyadmin and click to `customers` table and check that the record you wanted to delete is deleted or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
     $del="DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id='$id'";
```

Change *$del* with the line above